# How to call invoke JMX operation with arguments in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, jmx, jpype

I am trying to invoke JMX operations from Python using Jpype but I am getting error when I am passing arguments.

It works perfectly fine for operations not involving any arguments.

```
import jpype
from jpype import java
from jpype import javax

HOST='localhost'
PORT=9000
USER=''
PASS=''

URL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://%s:%d/jmxrmi" % (HOST, PORT)
#this it the path of your libjvm /usr/lib/jvm/sun-jdk-<version>/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so on linux
jpype.startJVM("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so")
java.lang.System.out.println("JVM load OK")

jhash = java.util.HashMap()
jarray=jpype.JArray(java.lang.String)([USER,PASS])
jhash.put (javax.management.remote.JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, jarray);
jmxurl = javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL(URL)
jmxsoc = javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxurl,jhash)
connection = jmxsoc.getMBeanServerConnection();

# This invoke operation works fine as it does not expect any arguments
object = 'Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="http-nio-8080"'
attribute = "hasNegotiableProtocols"
print(connection.invoke(javax.management.ObjectName(object),attribute, None, None))

# This invoke operation expects string argument ("admin" in this case)
object = "Users:type=UserDatabase,database=UserDatabase"
opt = "findUser"
connection.invoke(javax.management.ObjectName(object),opt,'admin',None)
```

Can someone advise how exactly the 3rd and 4th arguments be passed? I have searched a lot on internet but not found an example how this can be done in Python. All examples are using "None" and "None" as 3rd and 4th arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the method you are attempting to access is

```
Object  invoke(ObjectName name, String operationName, Object[] params, String[] signature)
```

Thus a raw string would not be accepted as the 3rd argument.  You must first create an object array.  For example:

```
args = jpype.JArray(jpype.JObject)(['admin'])
```

This is equivalent to the Java statement.

```
Object[] args = new Object[]{"admin"};
```

If you are calling this type of array a lot just create the list type once and then apply it where you need.

```
JObjectArray = jpype.JArray(jpype.JObject)
...
args = JObjectArray(["admin"])
```

The same thing applies to the 4th argument except that would need to be an array of strings.  `jpype.JArray(jpype.JString)`

Comment: Thanks Karl. Based on your suggestion I made these changes: `jarray_arg = jpype.JArray(jpype.JObject)(['admin'])` and `jsignature = jpype.JArray(jpype.JString)` and while invoking `connection.invoke(javax.management.ObjectName(object),opt,jarray_arg,jsignature)` but now I get another error: **connection.invoke(javax.management.ObjectName(object),opt,jarray_arg,jsignature) jpype._jexception.MBeanExceptionPyRaisable: javax.management.MBeanException: Cannot find operation findUser**. The Mbean exists though.

Comment: The 4th argument is incorrect.  You have declared jsignature as a list type not an actual list.  For example "print(jpype.JArray(jpype.JInt))" tells you that this is the type "<class 'jpype._jclass.int[]'>".  If I want an actual list I would use "print(jpype.JArray(jpype.JInt)([1,2]))".  Of course if you just want to pass ``null`` to the last argument use ``None``.   Most of this is covered in the quickstart guide to be published with JPype 0.7.0 shortly.  [link](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/devel/quickguide.html)

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience of java. So in this case, what should be jsignature. i tried with `jsignature = jpype.JArray(jpype.JString)(['admin']) ` but it does not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only help with how to translate calls to JPype. As to what arguments are accepted in JMX, I recommend finding a working Java example first.

Comment: What would be the python equivalent for fourth argument of this java line : `mbeanServerConn.invoke(ObjName, "startManagement", 
            new Object[0], new String[0])`?

Comment: `mbeanServerConn.invoke(ObjName, "startManagement", JArray(JObject)([]), JArray(JString)([]))`

Comment: FYI: If anybody is stuck this is how I got my call to work.     ```attribute = "methodName" ```  
    ```params = JArray(JObject)(["paramText"]) ```  
    ```sig = JArray(JString)(["java.lang.String"]) ```  
```print(connection.invoke(javax.management.ObjectName(object),attribute, params, sig))```